# JavaFX Roting 3D object with changing pivot point

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, transform

I am trying to rotate a group of shapes around a custom (changing) pivot point. Like in for example CATIA, I want to be able to click on one of those shapes within the group to define the pivot point. Then I want to be able to rotate the group around this pivot point by dragging the mouse in x or y. Like in Catia, I want to be able to define a new pivot point after each rotation and rotate the group around this new pivot point in x and y. The group should however not loose its previous orientation.
The problem is, that the first rotation works fine, but each following rotation pivots around something not defined by the mouse click.

Now trying this for weeks, I think I have figured out why this is not working. In the docs they say that the pivot point is set relative to the origin. So when I want to define a new pivot point, the point coordinates are understood as relative to the shape origin (where it was starting out) and not where the shape currently is due to rotation.

I have tried to save all past Rotate-Transforms in a list and apply them to the new pivot point BEFORE creating a new Rotate object and setting its pivot point. This also does not seem to work. I am not even sure, if this way is the right way.

Can somebody help me? On the mousePressedEvent, I convert the event-coordinates to scene-coordinates and then pass this information along with the scene and smartgroup to my newRotation()-method. This method then sets up the mouseDraggedEvent-Listener. This repeats for every mousePressedEvent. Below is my code:

```
import application.MouseControl;
import application.SmartGroup;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Cylinder;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Sphere;
import javafx.stage.Stage;  

public class Test extends Application{  



    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        // creating the rectangles   
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100,100,200,200);  
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(100,100,200,200);  
        Circle sphere1 = new Circle(100,100,10);
        Cylinder cli = new Cylinder(20,100);
        cli.setTranslateX(200);
        cli.setTranslateY(200);
        //spere1.setTranslateX(100);
        //spere1.setTranslateY(100);

        // setting the color and stroke for the Rectangles    
        rect1.setFill(Color.LIMEGREEN);  
        rect2.setFill(Color.DARKGREY);  
        rect1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);  
        rect2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);  

        // instantiating the Group

        SmartGroup root = new SmartGroup();
        SmartGroup rotationGroup = new SmartGroup();
        SmartGroup stationaryGroup = new SmartGroup();
        root.getChildren().add(rotationGroup);
        root.getChildren().add(stationaryGroup);
        stationaryGroup.getChildren().add(rect1);
        rotationGroup.getChildren().add(rect2);
        rotationGroup.getChildren().add(sphere1);
        rotationGroup.getChildren().add(cli);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,420, true);  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Rotation");  
        MouseControl control = new MouseControl();

        rect2.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            Point3D eventPoint = new Point3D(event.getX(),event.getY(),event.getZ());
            Sphere sphere2 = new Sphere(10);
            System.out.println("New sphere at location of pivot point created");
            Point3D scenePoint = new Point3D(rect2.localToScene(eventPoint).getX(), rect2.localToScene(eventPoint).getY(), rect2.localToScene(eventPoint).getZ());
            sphere2.setTranslateX(scenePoint.getX());
            sphere2.setTranslateY(scenePoint.getY());
            sphere2.setTranslateZ(scenePoint.getZ());
            root.getChildren().add(sphere2);
            control.newRotation(rotationGroup, scene, scenePoint);
        });
        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            Point3D scenePoint = new Point3D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(), control.getAnchorZ());
            control.newRotation(rotationGroup, scene, scenePoint);
        });
        primaryStage.show();  
    }
    public void startup(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch(args);  
    }
}
```

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
/**
 * 
 * @author nim
 * @description 
 * This class is used to control the transformation/rotation/zoom of a SmartGroup based on mouse events
 */
public class MouseControl {
    private double anchorX, anchorY; 
    private double anchorZ; 
    private double anchorAngleX = 0;
    private double anchorAngleY = 0;
    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> draggHandler;
    private Rotate xRotate;
    private Rotate yRotate;
    private Point3D transformedPoint;
    /**
     * 
     * @param group The rotation is applied to this group
     * @param scene Mouse-Listeners are attached to this scene
     * @param pivotPoint PivotPoint in SceneCoordinates
     */
    public void newRotation(SmartGroup group, Scene scene, Point3D pivotPoint) { 
        setAnchorZ(pivotPoint.getZ());
        if (draggHandler != null) {
            scene.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, draggHandler); 
            xRotate.angleProperty().unbind();
            yRotate.angleProperty().unbind();
        }
        group.getTransforms().addAll(
                xRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS),
                yRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS)
                );
        anchorX = pivotPoint.getX(); 
        anchorY = pivotPoint.getY();
        anchorAngleX = 0;
        anchorAngleY = 0;
        xRotate.setPivotX(pivotPoint.getX());
        xRotate.setPivotY(pivotPoint.getY());
        yRotate.setPivotX(pivotPoint.getX());
        yRotate.setPivotY(pivotPoint.getY());
        xRotate.setPivotZ(pivotPoint.getZ());
        yRotate.setPivotZ(pivotPoint.getZ());
        //create new MouseDraggedEvent
        DoubleProperty angleX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty angleY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> mDragged = (draggedEvent -> {
            angleX.set(anchorAngleX - (anchorY - draggedEvent.getSceneY()));
            angleY.set(anchorAngleY + (anchorX - draggedEvent.getSceneX())); 
        });
        xRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleX);
        yRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleY);
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(mDragged);
        draggHandler = mDragged;
    }
    public double getAnchorX() {
        return anchorX;
    }
    public void setAnchorX(double anchorX) {
        this.anchorX = anchorX;
    }
    public double getAnchorY() {
        return anchorY;
    }
    public void setAnchorY(double anchorY) {
        this.anchorY = anchorY;
    }
    public double getAnchorZ() {
        return anchorZ;
    }
    public void setAnchorZ(double anchorZ) {
        this.anchorZ = anchorZ;
    }
    public double getAnchorAngleX() {
        return anchorAngleX;
    }
    public void setAnchorAngleX(double anchorAngleX) {
        this.anchorAngleX = anchorAngleX;
    }
    public double getAnchorAngleY() {
        return anchorAngleY;
    }
    public void setAnchorAngleY(double anchorAngleY) {
        this.anchorAngleY = anchorAngleY;
    }
    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getDraggHandler() {
        return draggHandler;
    }
    public void setDraggHandler(EventHandler<MouseEvent> draggHandler) {
        this.draggHandler = draggHandler;
    }
    public Rotate getxRotate() {
        return xRotate;
    }
    public void setxRotate(Rotate xRotate) {
        this.xRotate = xRotate;
    }
    public Rotate getyRotate() {
        return yRotate;
    }
    public void setyRotate(Rotate yRotate) {
        this.yRotate = yRotate;
    }

}
```

Comment: I should say that the class SmartGroup is just extended from the JavaFX class Group and does not override any of its methods.